# Name tikz circuit symbol node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Consider the following minimal example in with `TikZ circuit library`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [circuit ee IEC,>=latex]
\draw (0,0) to [bulb] (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to assign a name to this bulb, say `(B)`. And reuse this point like for example:

```
\draw let \p1=(B.output) in (B.output) -- (\x1,-2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass options to the `bulb` node in its argument, so for example `... to [bulb={name=B}] ...` (you can also use any other options you can pass to nodes, like `thick`, `red`, `label=A lightbulb`, etc.).

Note that instead of using the `let` syntax from your example, in this case you could simply use relative coordinates using `+`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [circuit ee IEC,>=latex]
\draw (0,0) to [bulb={name=B}] (3,0);
\draw (B.output) -- +(0,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```